# Resignation on the promotion day

Tags: resignation

I am working in a software company where things haven’t been financially sound recently. Since there will most likely be some layoffs soon, I started searching for other opportunities. I had an interview about a month ago and then a few days later I got a letter from my current manager that I will be promoted after a month and a half with a title change. At that point I had no feedback from the company I interviewed with.

About 3 weeks later I recieved the promotion letter from my current employer. The company I interviewed with also gave me an offer, which I decided to accept after all. I decided this due to the risk of layoff and the offer being better for my career growth and from a financial point of view.

Giving a two-week notice is standard where I work and if I do the same, I will basically be giving my notice on the day my title changes. The other option is giving the notice prior to that (basically a 3-week notice) but then there is a chance that my title will remain the same since I am leaving.

Should I wait and give the standard 2 week notice, even though my promotion takes effect that same day?

Comment: Can't you give a two-week notice _now_ and then take a week off?

Comment: Is there anyone else considered for that promotion? Or do you just get a 'senior' in front of your current title?

Answer (score 19):

The question you have to ask yourself is, does it really matter what your job title will be for two weeks, especially when you're leaving?  You have already accepted a new role, so the old job title is not needed for you to find employment.  For the vast majority of your time in the previous company, you have held the old title, so it could be considered by some employers to be disingenuous to claim the promoted title.

In the end, you are moving on and first and foremost you need to ensure that you follow the protocols in giving notice and doing a high-quality handover.  The promoted title is not likely to stick whether you give your notice on the day or a week prior, and really it's just not important.

Do a professional handover, move on to your new job and not worry about the promotion where you are leaving; you're leaving anyway! :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I definitely won’t benefit from being promoted for only two weeks and I certainly want to do a professional move to my new job. So, maybe if I rephrase my question, would it be more professional to give longer than 2 week notice in this special circumstance or am I overthinking it as Joe mentioned?

Comment: @JavaNerd You are definitely overthinking this :)  Just give your mandated notice period with professional handover for the job you have been doing (not the promoted job you haven't actually taken on yet!) and enjoy your new role :)

Answer (score 12):

> Giving two-week notice is standard where I work and if I do the same,
>   I will basically be giving my notice on the day my title changes. The
>   other option is giving the notice prior to that (basically a 3-week
>   notice) but then there is a chance that My title will remain the same
>   since I am leaving.
>
> I would appreciate any advice.

Just give your expected two week notice and move on. It's an awkward coincidence that you will resign the same day you expect to be promoted, but nothing more than that.

There's no need  to overthink this one.